# Google Chrome hangs for 20+ seconds before loading URL

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium

When opening Google Chrome, I can interact with the UI and task manager shows no significant resource usage, but when I navigate to a URL there is a 20+ second delay. I can open multiple tabs and attempt to navigate to multiple URLs but they will all hang until suddenly all of the tabs load at once.

This only happens the first time I open the browser and then each URL navigated after the delay loads immediately. It also happens when using Incognito mode, each time a new window is opened.

If I open a new window and wait 20 seconds and then navigate to a URL, it loads instantly. If I open a new window and wait 10 seconds and then navigate to a URL, the delay is 10 seconds before the URL starts to load. So the issue seems to be related to startup of a new chromium instance.

I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome
- Disabling all extensions
- Disabling hardware acceleration
- Updated graphics driver to latest
- Ensured no proxy config in place
- Other devices on my network do not have this problem, so it is not the network or internet connection
- Disabling network discovery

The issue seems to have started with the most recent Windows update that added Copilot to the task bar. Is anyone else experiencing this? I can't find many people posting online.

*Update:* I opened Chrome in debug mode using `--enable-logging --v=1` and there was no debug log output while Chrome was hanging. I tested some invalid URLs to make sure that the logging process was working. When opening Chrome and navigating to a valid URL, there was no output to the debug log during or after the delay.

Comment: Try to: (1) [Turn off automatic network discovery](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1049382/).  (2) In *Settings > Apps > Installed apps*, find Edge, click the 3-point menu and select Modify to repair it.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc but neither of those solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by going to:
Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy

I turned OFF setting "Automatically detect settings"

[image]